# Error trying to get uids of emails in large folders using IMAP and Twisted

Tags: python, imap, twisted, twisted.internet, twisted.client

I am writing an IMAP client using the last version of Twisted.

I am having trouble using two different ways for getting email UIDs.

First i have tried to use the search method this way :

```
@inlineCallbacks
def getEmailList(self):
    for f in folder_list:
        rep = yield self.examine(f)
        uids_list = yield self.search(imap4.Query(all=True), uid=True)
```

This works but when I try to use it on large folders (containing more than 10.000 messages) the command fails.

I got an error like :

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/policies.py", line 120, in dataReceived
    self.wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 571, in dataReceived
    why = self.lineReceived(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2360, in lineReceived
    self._regularDispatch(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2388, in _regularDispatch
    self.dispatchCommand(tag, rest)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2417, in dispatchCommand
    f(tag, rest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2446, in response_UNAUTH
    self._defaultHandler(tag, rest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2467, in _defaultHandler
    raise IllegalServerResponse(tag + ' ' + rest)
twisted.mail.imap4.IllegalServerResponse: 1428 111429 111430 111431 111432
```

So am I doing wrong ? Or can I handle the server answer in a better way ?

I tried something else for passing through this problem.
Instead of using search method I tried to replace :

```
uids_list = yield self.search(imap4.Query(all=True), uid=True)
```

by

```
rep = yield self.fetchUID('1:*')
uids_list = set([x['UID'] for x in rep.values()])
```

This works too (slower than previous method sometimes) but when I try to use it on imap.mail.yahoo.com it fails with this error :

```
[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class'twisted.mail.imap4.IMAP4Exception'>: [CLIENTBUG] FETCH Bad sequence in the command]
```

This is strange because when I run the same command using imaplib I don't get any error so did I miss something ?

EDIT : I resolve this problem. The IMAP4 server of yahoo seems to have a pretty strange implementation. In fact, if we ask for a sequence that does not exists in the folder. For example (was my case) if the folder is empty and we send:

```
FETCH 1:* (UID)
```

The server fails with :

```
BAD [CLIENTBUG] FETCH Bad sequence in the command
```

So for bypassing this error I just check the answer of examine like that :

```
rep = yield self.examine(f)
if rep['EXISTS'] != 0:
    rep = yield self.fetchUID('1:*')
    uids_list = set([x['UID'] for x in rep.values()])
```

Thanks by advance for any hint or answer,

Answer (score 0):

That *is* a client bug. If you refer to message number 1 and the server has told you that there are 0 messages, the bug is plainly yours. The same applies if the server has told you that there are 1000 messages and you refer to number 1001.

Listen to the `EXISTS` responses. Or switch to using UID (and listen to the `UIDNEXT` response codes).